# Одна третя чи одна третина?

Tags: вибір-слова, числівники

В художній літературі, підручниках, статтях є безліч прикладів вживання словосполучення "*одна третина*".

У [Складних випадках українського слововживання](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=21306) прочитала, що це неправильно, потрібно казати "*одна третя*" або "*третина*". Чи справді це так, чи це просто рекомендація?

Інших підтверджень чи спростувань цьому не знайшла. І якщо так, то чи це правило відноситься також до *2/3, 2/4*, тобто як правильно казати "*дві третини/четвертини*", чи "*дві третіх/четвертих*"?

Answer (score 2):

Згідно з [українським правописом-2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#drobovi)

> **§ 72. Відмінювання дробових числівників**
>
> 1. Дробові числівники читаються так: 1/2 — одна друга, **1/3** — **одна третя**, 1/4 — одна четверта, 5/2 — п’ять других, **2/3 — дві треті**, 3/4 —
>    три четверті, 4/3 — чотири треті, 3/5 — три п’яті, 2/7 — дві сьомі,
>    9/10 — дев’ять десятих.
>
> Відмінюються вони як звичайні числівники: двом третім, трьома п’ятими;
> ділити на одну двадцяту.
>
> Половина (1/2), **третина** (1/3), чверть (1/4), відмінюються як звичайні
> іменники.

На сайті [Уроки державної мови](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/228.htm) зазначено:

> У доповідях, звітах уникають уживання простого дробу зі знаменниками
> 2, 3, 4: замість 1/2, 1/3, 1/4 пишуть і говорять ***половина, третина,
> чверть.*** Але при протиставленні, а також при спеціальному наголошенні
> можуть використовуватися й дробові числівники. *"Одна третя студентів
> інституту поїхала на виробничу практику в західні області України, а
> дві треті — в центральні"* (з газети).
>
> Коли співвідношення 1/3 або 1/4 передаються словами третина, чверть,
> то перед ними не треба ставити числівник одна ***(неправильно: одна
> третина, одна чверть)***

З СУМ

> [ТРЕТИНА](http://sum.in.ua/s/tretyna) и, жін. Одна з трьох рівних частин чого-небудь. *Треба
> було, щоб аж дві третини всієї громади згодилися продати землю, а коли
> до двох третин не ставало, то й не вільно продавати* (Борис Грінченко,
> II, 1963, 377)

Отже, говорити одна третина - неправильно, правильно **одна третя** або **третина**. Відповідно правильно буде говоритти 2/3 - **дві треті**, 2/4 - **дві четверті**